# UIWebView shows whitespace when scrolling to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am working on a basic iOS app with UIWebView to load a page in full-screen mode. I can scroll the page, but when I scroll to the top it shows white space. How can it be removed? [image: White Space]

Comment: Apply top bottom constraints to your uiwebview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daljeet is absolutely right, I think. If you apply constraints to the top, it should cut off before going into white space.

I'm fairly sure that you can do this in the Size Inspector, here?[image]

I hope this helps. Sorry if the Size Inspector isn't where you apply constraints. I haven't had to do that in a while. :)